# How to intrepret "noch" in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

> Wenn du es getan hast, hat sie das vielleicht eher **noch** darin bestärkt, dass sie recht hat!

I'm torn between two interpretations here:

---

> 1. Contrary to your expectations, it ***only*** served to have her convinced that ...

You did something in the hope of turning around the situation, ***only*** to have her convinced that ...

*Noch* {einschränkend} is close in meaning to *nur*.

---

> 2. By doing that,  you made her ***all the more*** convinced that ...

The same *noch* as the one used in the {Vergleichen} locution such as "noch stärker" with the meaning of "***even more*** / ***still more***".

Comment: Both your interpretations *could* apply based on the (minimum) German sentence - Without further context, you wouldn't know how to translate (and that is true even if you omit the "noch" from the German sentence).

Comment: There's a **may** missing in both your examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, your second interpretation describes the actual meaning of the sentence much better than the first.  However, you have skipped the "vielleicht".  That's why @Janka wrote "there's a may missing" - if we slot it in, we get: "you *may* have made her all the more convinced that ..."

Where I'm not quite sure is the first part of your sentence 2.: 
You have translated "Wenn du es getan hast ..." into "By doing that ..."
Again - for me, personally - it should be: "If you have done it, ..."

Cobbling it all together, you could write:
"If you have done it, you may made her all the more convinced that ..."

I still don't like this translation eg the meaning of "convinced" is closer to "überzeugt" than to "bestärkt" and I think, once someone is convinced, they are convinced :-).  So - maybe we should write: "... it may have given her another reason to think that she's right."

(One more thought "for the road" as it were ...)
What I would like to add is: in your first translation, you have used ONLY.  This would be right, if the sentence contained NUR NOCH.  However, we've got EHER NOCH which means something like "rather".